# uninstall dockerce/moby from windows server 2019

Tags: powershell, windows-server, windows-server-2019, docker-ce, moby

Following the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=dockerce), I installed docker CE on a windows 2019 server using:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/Windows-Containers/Main/helpful_tools/Install-DockerCE/install-docker-ce.ps1" -o install-docker-ce.ps1
.\install-docker-ce.ps1
```

I regret it and want to get rid of it. It installed successfully but did not create a folder in the Programs directory. So I wonder where the files are and how I can fully uninstall the whole thing. It is really hard to find any related documentation about this whole project :/

The [recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon) way of removal for Windows 2016 Servers does not work:

```
PS C:\Users\ABC> Uninstall-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider
Uninstall-Package : Es wurden keine Paketanbieter (DockerMsftProvider) gefunden.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ Uninstall-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Power...ninstallPackage:UninstallPackage) [Uninstall-Package
   ], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnknownProviders,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.UninstallPackage
```

The following Commands do not even list docker as an installed package:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> wmic
wmic:root\cli>product get name, version, vendo
```

Comment: Have you checked ProgramData and not the Program Files dir?

Comment: after reading your comment, I wanted to verify it for sure and figured out the folder "docker" was hidden inside ProgramData (yaaay windows). I ended up removing everything related to Docker by hand. I was too tired doing it properly...

Answer (score -1):

```
"C:\Program Files\Docker\dockerd.exe" --unregister-service
```